# How to have eclipse and android studio both in one mac?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio, this one is working fine and I really liked it, the problem was wen I opened Eclipse again, I got this message:

"This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.

Current version is 22.6.2.v201403212031-1085508.

Please update ADT to the lastest version."

So I dont know what to do because the SDK location of both is the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to update your ADT to the latest version of the plugin ，
Eclipse ADT package update url :[http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html]
Then you can configure Android studio && Eclipse with the same SDK，
configure you eclipse sdk location to sdk install path.

example:

SDK Location : /Users/mac/Program/android-sdk-mac

Configure Eclipse : select menu  Window --> Preferences -->android , and set your SDK Location.

Configure Android Studio :

1.if you first install android studio ,You can select an existing SDK in the installation wizard

2.if you already installtion android studio,you can use the menu configuration